# BeautifulSoup Scraping Span Class HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from the `<span class= ''>`.  The code looks like this on the pages I am scraping:

```
    < span class = "catnum"> Disc Number < / span>
    "1"
    < br >
    < span class = "catnum"> Track Number < / span>
    "1"
    < br>
    < span class = "catnum" > Duration < /span>
    "5:28"
    <br>
```

What I need to get are those numbers after the `</span>` tag.  I should also mention I am writing a larger piece of code that is scraping 1200 sites and this will have to loop over 1200 sites where the numbers in the quotation marks will change from page to page.

I tried this code as a test on one page:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    soup = BeautifulSoup (open("Smith.html"), "html.parser")

    for tag in soup.findAll('span'):
        if tag.has_key('class'):
            if tag['class'] == 'catnum':
                print tag.string
```

I know that will print ALL the  'span class' tags and not just the three I want, but I thought I would still test it to see if it worked and I got this error:

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py:1527: UserWarning:
> has_key is deprecated. Use has_attr("class") instead.   key))

Comment: `[span.next_sibling.strip() for span in  soup.select("span.catnum")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said in the error message, you should use `tag.has_attr("class")` in place of the deprecated `tag.has_key("class")` method.

Hope it helps.

Simone

Comment: That did get ride of the error, but now nothing is printing so I don't know if it grabbed the right thing.

The other problem I am having is I need the numbers in the quotations and not the text .

Comment: I know, but you asked the reason of the error and I answered that question. I don't understand the reason for the thumb down.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that ´tag['class']` return the class name in the form `[u'catnum']`, so you have to check for that specific string, or check if it contains the string you are looking for.

for tag in soup.findAll('span'): 
    if tag.has_attr('class'):
        if 'catnum' in tag['class']:
      print tag.string

Here a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain your search by attribute `{'class': 'catnum'}` and the text inside `text=re.compile('Disc Number')`. Then use `.next_sibling` to find the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
s = '''
    <span class = "catnum"> Disc Number </span>
    "1"
    <br/>
    <span class = "catnum"> Track Number </span>
    "1"
    <br/>
    <span class = "catnum"> Duration </span>
    "5:28"
    <br/>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'catnum'}, text=re.compile(r'Disc Number'))
print span.next_sibling
```